# Pandas merge_asof: Database is not merging together

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data which i am trying to merge using pd.merge_asof. The problem is that the end result by reviewing GPS_DATA, it does not seem to have any matches or merging performed

Step taken to remedy

1. I have tot that the tolerance may be too little... I try to increase them but there is no change in answer
2. I have tried to look at ZXY_DATA (even though I believe merge_asof is similar to LEFT JOIN), there is still no changes
3. I begin to wonder whether it is becuase of multiple similar entries (should i instead use Time to join)... Edit Time was created by pd.to_datetime(GPS_Data['Time']) but Time is a string field directly from the sensor.. it was converted to Date Time.

Is there a way to convert DateTime format to account for decimal place differences?

Code

```
tol = pd.Timedelta('0.05 second')
pd.merge_asof(left=GPS_DATA, right=ZXY_DATA.sort_values('Edit Time'), on='Edit Time',direction='nearest',tolerance=tol)
```

ZXY_data

```
Time    Edit Time   ZXYx    ZXYy
0   13:36:48.730    2019-11-14 13:36:48 374229.910784405    156560.954590241
1   13:36:52.178    2019-11-14 13:36:52 374229.855169092    156560.987783082
2   13:36:52.610    2019-11-14 13:36:52 374229.755059369    156561.043108102
3   13:36:53.139    2019-11-14 13:36:53 374229.666075945    156561.098427695
4   13:36:53.619    2019-11-14 13:36:53 374229.554850706    156561.175868615
5   13:36:54.067    2019-11-14 13:36:54 374229.410262753    156561.286491522
6   13:36:54.475    2019-11-14 13:36:54 374229.132191573    156561.463510966
7   13:36:54.603    2019-11-14 13:36:54 374228.909730317    156561.596282333
8   13:36:55.067    2019-11-14 13:36:55 374228.665021856    156561.74011979
9   13:36:55.507    2019-11-14 13:36:55 374228.420324181    156561.906067719
10  13:36:56.011    2019-11-14 13:36:56 374228.14224761     156562.072031929
```

GPS_Data:

```
14  13:36:48.000    2019-11-14 13:36:48 374226.918743055    156562.868605879
15  13:36:48.400    2019-11-14 13:36:48 374226.295869875    156563.277953521
16  13:36:48.599    2019-11-14 13:36:48 374225.917699762    156563.532408467
17  13:36:48.799    2019-11-14 13:36:48 374225.517271661    156563.775819032
18  13:36:49.000    2019-11-14 13:36:49 374225.105722654    156564.030290262
19  13:36:49.200    2019-11-14 13:36:49 374224.683047349    156564.284766919
20  13:36:49.400    2019-11-14 13:36:49 374224.249256532    156564.561359478
21  13:36:49.599    2019-11-14 13:36:49 374223.804339418    156564.837957465
22  13:36:49.799    2019-11-14 13:36:49 374223.359433089    156565.136665927
23  13:36:50.000    2019-11-14 13:36:50 374222.914515975    156565.413263917
24  13:36:50.200    2019-11-14 13:36:50 374222.458483349    156565.711977809
25  13:36:50.400    2019-11-14 13:36:50 374221.969077221    156566.02176322
26  13:36:50.599    2019-11-14 13:36:50 374221.513060773    156566.353642825
27  13:36:50.799    2019-11-14 13:36:50 374221.045907245    156566.663417386
28  13:36:51.000    2019-11-14 13:36:51 374220.545396392    156567.017429176
29  13:36:51.200    2019-11-14 13:36:51 374220.078264432    156567.371424687
30  13:36:51.400    2019-11-14 13:36:51 374219.60001157 156567.736480863
31  13:36:51.599    2019-11-14 13:36:51 374219.121769494    156568.123647515
32  13:36:51.799    2019-11-14 13:36:51 374218.632411906    156568.532930069
```

Answer (score 0):

Is edit time datetime type? Would it be possible not to be matching because of specific microseconds embeded in edit time?

Comment: Yes I converted Time to pd.to_datetime(GPS_DATA["TIme"])

Comment: Case Closed... Realise there is some mistake on my part... the answer came up perfectly

Comment: Now i have a problem of duplicate entries